# curl to "upload" file contents

Tags: php, file, curl, binary

im currently trying to upload the contents of a binary file (encrypted with openssl aes) via curl to a php Script.

The PHP Code looks like that:

```
if($_POST["content"] == ""){
}
else{
   $myfile = fopen("file.txt","w");
   fwrite($myfile,$_POST["content"]);
   fclose($myfile);
}
```

so i would normally do:

```
curl -d "content=<DATA>" http://www.example.com/script.php
```

But as i have a Binary File, that seemed to not work, so i tryed out curl -d with the @ symbol and via -F, but neither worked cause i need to post ist into the "content" part of $_POST.

How would i get that to work correctly?

Comment: why use commmand line curl? Why not use curl-in-php and do the upload there, instead of writing out to a file firsT?

Comment: the PHP Script is on a external webserver, the curl command is executed on my home computer. Thats the reason. The PHP Script should retrieve the data uploaded by the culr command and save it on the webserver.

Comment: Noone has a clue? :/

Comment: Here is the answer -> [Upload file using curl command line][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142344/upload-file-using-curl-command-line-in-dokuwiki